# c how to check the first char of an array

Tags: c, if-statement, types, serial-port

I am trying to take in 10 characters over a serial console and add them to an array called buffer. The first character needs to be 'L' or 'S' and the next characters either '1' or '0'.

The code passes the first if statement ok. But the line `if((buffer[0] != 'L') || (buffer[0] != 'S'))` doesn't seem to work even when I enter 'L' OR 'S'.

Is there anything wrong with using the `buffer[0] !=` notation?

```
int main(void)
{
char ch;
char buffer[10] = "";

putstring("Enter 9 characters beginning with 'L' or 'S' and 8 digits\r\n");

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

    ch = getcharacter();

    if ((ch == '0') || (ch == '1') || (ch == 'L') || (ch == 'S')) {

        buffer[i] = ch;
        //check first character
        if((buffer[0] != 'L') || (buffer[0] != 'S')) {

            printf("First letter must be L or S\r\n");
            goto error;
        }
        error:
        return -1;
    }
}
}
```

---

```
int getcharacter(void) {

char c = 0;
const uint32_t recieve_ready = 1 << 7;

//disable interrupt for a read ready
*uart_control_reg = 0;

while (1) {
    //check if RRDY bit is set
    if ((*uart_status_reg) & recieve_ready) {
        c = *uart_rxdata_reg;
        break;
    }
}
return ((char) c);
```

}

Comment: `if((buffer[0] != 'L') || (buffer[0] != 'S'))`, if buffer[0] is an 'S', then first condition is true, then you get the error, same goes for the 'L' (second condition true)

Comment: doesn't really matter if the first character is L or S as it'll still hit the `return -1` anyway

Comment: Avoid `goto` wherever possible

Comment: @user64322 - always avoid absolutes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using

```
if((buffer[0] != 'L') && (buffer[0] != 'S'))
```

instead of

```
if((buffer[0] != 'L') || (buffer[0] != 'S'))
```

Just some  logic problem here. According to your code, the char needs to be equal to 'L' AND 'S' to avoid the condition, which is never the case !

Answer (score 7):

```
if((buffer[0] != 'L') || (buffer[0] != 'S'))
```

is wrong, you need

```
if((buffer[0] != 'L') && (buffer[0] != 'S'))
```

or

```
if (!(buffer[0] == 'L' || buffer[0] == 'S'))
```

Your original code was "if the char is not L or the char is not S" which is always true. If the char is L, then the second part was true, making the whole if statement true.

Just noticed Chris Turner's comment above. The `return -1` is always executed, move it to replace the line that says `goto error`.